# Running a elevated cmd prompt command python

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I've searched google etc but am struggling to find a suitable answer...

Whats the easiest way of opening an elevated cmd prompt in python and having python run a command in it?  I don't mind specifying the username and password in the code as its only for testing

So far I've come up with this:

`subprocess.run(["Enable_IPRouting.bat"])`

The 'Enable_IPRouting.bat' simply contains the following at the min:

`runas /profile /user:DESKTOP-GRLIH2J\Administrator cmd`

Now when I run this - it appears to work I get a prompt requesting the admin password and a cmd prompt appears.
However when I try to execute a cmd that requires admin privileges I get the usual error:
`The requested operation requires elevation`

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: RunAs doesn't elevate it merely runas as a user.

Comment: Thanks - is there a way to elevate it then?

Comment: Right click and choose Run As Administrator or write an exe and put a manifest in it. This shows how to write an console exe with a manifest https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/rem-three-files-followrem.html.

Comment: If you copy your python program and edit it's manifest with http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/ then you can choose between an elevated or unelevated python.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried e.g.

```
os.system('runas /profile /user:DESKTOP-GRLIH2J\Administrator enable_iprouting.cmd')
```

(if `enable_iprouting.cmd` contains the stuff to run elevated)?

Comment: I've just tried it and I get a `Attempting to start enable_iprouting2.bat as user "DESKTOP-GRLIH2J\Administrator"` within the VSCode terminal - but then nothing happens.